# Android: AIDL, why List<String> works but List<Integer> doesn't

Tags: android, aidl

In Android, 
I am trying to create aidl file and trying to pass - 
    List
 shows -doesn't support java.lang.Integer it only supports primitives

But 
    List 
works good.

Can someone explain why that so

Answer (score 1):

you can't use it because AIDL doesn't support `Integer` it only supports primitives, but you can use some tricks like :

```
List<Integer> mList;
int[] mIntArray = new int[mList.size()];
for(Integer x :mList) {
    mIntArray[i] = x;
};
```

or

```
int[] mIntArray = mList.toArray(mList.size());
```

Comment: Easier to use mList.toArray(mIntArray);

Comment: i added thanks for the information , the array = list.toarray()

Comment: @Aroua: How come it supports String? List<String> works good. Why it so ?